# Creating an Angular Animation that can use an @Input() value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation, angular-animations

Is it possible to create an Angular Animation with custom parameters passed in via a function, and then using the resulting animation within a component?

[For example in this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iwdg7u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslide-in-animation.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fanimation.ts) the animation is created in a separate `animations.ts` like this:

```
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  animate,
  group,
} from '@angular/animations';

export const SlideInOutAnimation = [
  trigger('slideInOut', [
    state(
      'in',
      style({
        width: '50%',
        opacity: '1',
        visibility: 'visible',
      })
    ),
    state(
      'out',
      style({
        width: '50px',
        opacity: 0.3,
        visibility: 'visible',
      })
    ),
    transition('in => out', [
      group([
        animate(
          '600ms ease-in-out',
          style({
            width: '50px',
          })
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
    transition('out => in', [
      group([
        animate(
          '1ms ease-in-out',
          style({
            visibility: 'visible',
          })
        ),
        animate(
          '600ms ease-in-out',
          style({
            width: '50%',
          })
        ),
        animate(
          '800ms ease-in-out',
          style({
            opacity: '1',
          })
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
  ]),
];
```

And this animation can then be imported an used in a component that declares the animation in the `animations` property of the `@Component` decorator.

But what if we want to take an `@Input` property value and pass that to the animation.

For example if we have something like:

```
@Input()
width: 50%;
```

How would we pass this parameter to the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations with "parameters" are not so difficult.

Imagine something simple.

```
animations:[
    trigger('custom',[
      transition('*=>*', [
        style({ width: `{{width}}`  }),
        animate('500ms ease-in', style({ width: `100%`  })),
      ],{params:{ width: "0"}}),
    ])
 ]
```

We include the "parameters" in the "params" (that it's an object) and when we want to use it's enclosed by `{{` `}}`.

It's necessary to indicate a params by defect.

Then only, when define the animation in the .html is pass the parameters, e.g. if you have two variables "value" and "width" you can have a html like

```
<div class="header" [@custom]="{value:value,params:{width:width}}" >
```

Then, when we change the "value" the animation begins

```
<button (click)="width='50%';value=!value">width:50%</button>
<button (click)="width='0';value=!value">width:0</button>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3xvan?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

In the Stackblitz I use a variable in the component, but you can use an Input, but remember that if you want animation begings you need change the "value" (unless you use :enter and :leave)

Comment: This is an Angular 17 demo just in case anyone needs an updated environment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-q5wh73?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter